# Akka.Net switching behavior with Become()

Tags: akka.net

I have built as simple actor which accepts two messages: **TicketValidated** and **BarrierPush** but the switching is not happening as intended.

```
 public class TurnstileActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public TurnstileActor()
    {
        Become(Locked); 
    }
    public void Locked()
    {
        Receive<TicketValidated>(msg => Become(Unlocked));
        Receive<BarrierPush>(msg => { Console.WriteLine("Locked");});
    }

    public void Unlocked()
    {
        Receive<TicketValidated>(msg => 
            Console.WriteLine("Unlocked"));
        Receive<BarrierPush>(msg => Become(Locked));
    }
}
```

Main class

```
var system = ActorSystem.Create("ActorSystem");
var actor = system.ActorOf<TurnstileActor>("actor");

actor.Tell(new TicketValidated());
```

Actual execution is: the **Locked()** method is called from the constructor and **TicketValidated** message is received. **Become(Unlocked)** is executed correctly and it enters **Unlocked()** method but then **Console.WriteLine("Unlocked")** is not called.

Could the Akka.Net library be broken?

Comment: It looks like working as intended. You've passed one message to an actor in `Locked` behavior, which was handled by it by changing its behavior to `Unlocked`. Since you didn't do anything more, that's where the logic ends: actor is now `Unlocked` and message is considered handled. If you want it to print the text you wanted, you'd need to send another message to it, to trigger the handler of `Unlocked` behavior.

Comment: @BartoszSypytkowski thanks for shedding light to my question, however I'm still confused since I took the code from the book [Akka.net](https://www.manning.com/books/reactive-applications-with-akka-net). Can you elaborate how would you implement it?

Comment: The question is: what do you actually want to implement? This piece of code is pretty much excercise on how behavior switching works. While it may not work as you imagined it to, it doesn't mean it doesn't work as intended. If you want to print behavior on console when it's being switched, you can just put your print statement in the behavior method body, outside of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this behaviour, consider what happens when Become(Unlocked) is executed, and it enters the Unlocked() method. The Unlocked method in turn invokes the Receive method twice: These 2 calls to Receive register the new behaviour of this actor, affecting **subsequent** messages sent to this actor instance. The lambdas passed in to the Receive methods are not executed at this time - they represent the new behaviour that is registered, and that will be seen when subsequent messages are received.

That explains why "Unlocked" is not written to the console when "Become(Unlocked)" is executed - It will only be seen if the **next** message received is another "TicketValidated".